# Normal subgroup and singleton orbits

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, normal-subgroups

Here is the exercise 20.11 from [Groups and Symmetry from Armstrong](https://books.google.fr/books?id=lDfcBPl9Cu4C&printsec=frontcover&hl=en#v=onepage&q=group%20and%20symmetry&f=false) :

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and write $X$ for the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$. We have the action : $$ g(xH) = gxH$$
>   Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup iff every orbit of the induced action of $H$ on $X$ contains just one point.

$\Rightarrow h(xH)=hxH=hHx=xH$ so it is clear that $G(xH)=\lbrace xH \rbrace $

For the other way I don't know how to do.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @DavidPopović for $\Rightarrow$, with normality we have $gH=Hg$ so $h(xH)=hxH=hHx=xH$ with $g \in G, h \in H$. For the other way I don't know where to start.

Comment: Your argument implies, $x^{-1}hx\in H$ for any $x\in G$ from which result follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already done one implication. The other one is as follows:

For any $h \in H$ and $x \in G$, you have $h(xH)=xH$, so $h \in xHx^{-1}$. So $H = xHx^{-1}$ for any $x$ which means that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: Isn't $|O(xH)| = [G:\operatorname{Stab}(xH)] = [G:xHx^{-1}] = [G:H]$?

Comment: No, because the group that acts is $H$.

Comment: Oh yes! I had missed that and thought automatically to $G$ as acting group. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem:

\begin{alignat}{1}
|O(xH)| &= [H:\operatorname{Stab}_H(xH)],\space\forall x \in G \\
\end{alignat}

where

\begin{alignat}{1}
\operatorname{Stab}_H(xH) &= \{h\in H\mid hxH=xH\} \\
&= \{h\in G\mid hxH=xH\wedge h\in H\} \\
&= H\cap xHx^{-1}, \space\forall x\in G
\end{alignat}

Therefore,

\begin{alignat}{1}
&|O(xH)|=1,\space\forall x\in G \iff \\
&H\cap xHx^{-1}=H,\space\forall x\in G \iff \\
&H\subseteq xHx^{-1},\space\forall x\in G \iff \\
&H\unlhd G
\end{alignat}